# React Router render error when using Link inside the Route element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme, react-router-dom

I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0", and I wil get this error.

```
  Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You never need more than one
```

Here is the code.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import SpiderSolitaire from './Pages/SpiderSolitaire';
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
   return (

<Router>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path="/game" element={<SpiderSolitaire />}/>
    </Routes>
 </Router>
 );
 }

  export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate  } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Home.scss";
import PlayingCards from "../../assets/spider.png"
import Spider from "../../assets/bb.png"
function Home() {

 return (
     <div data-test="home-app" className="home">
     <h1 data-test="home-header">Welcome Reversed Spider SpiderSolitaire</h1>
     <div data-test="home-image-wrapper" className="flex">
      <img data-test="home-image" src={PlayingCards} alt="playingCards" width="300"/>
     </div>
     <div data-test="home-rules-wrapper" className="rules">
      <h2 data-test="home-rules-header">How To Play ?</h2>
      <ul>
        <li data-test="home-rule-1">To win a hand, the cards must always be arranged in the 
          order A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10, J, Q, K.</li>
        <li data-test="home-rule-2">When the game is deadlocked or when you need a card, click 
           on the top left and after that 10 new cards are placed on the deck.</li>
        <li data-test="home-rule-3">Of the fifty-four cards laid out on the table at the 
         beginning of the game, only the top cards are face-up.</li>
        <li data-test="home-rule-4">If the face of the face up card changes, the face of the 
         previous card is revealed.</li>
        <li data-test="home-rule-5">To win the game, there must be 8 sets of hands at the end 
         of the game.</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <Link to={"/game"}>
     <button data-test="home-game-button" className="startGame" >Start to  Game</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
    );
    }

    export default Home;
```

When I delete Link in Home and use useNavigate, it works. But the problem is when I test the code it gives error like this.

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useNavigate) is not a function

   7 | function Modal( ) {
   8 |
>  9 |   const navigate = useNavigate();
     |                    ^
  10 |   const playAgain = () =>{
  11 |     navigate.push("/");
  12 |   }
```

Is there any possible way to direct to user to route? Or How I can do it differently.

Comment: Are you sure you are on `react-router-dom` v5.2.0? `Routes` and `useNavigate` are new in v6. Is your issue occurring when running your app normally, or is it only during unit testing? Also, in home.js, you are `import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';` this is clearly an error.

Comment: Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `import` statement in `Home.js`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

should be,

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```